# iOS UILabel sometimes is not displaying the correct color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using a UILabel to display text, sometimes it display correct color and sometimes not. I am using a simple UILabel object, below is my code:

```
UILabel *costomerTel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
costomerTel.textColor = RSColor(@"#0b192e");
costomerTel.font = RSFont(12);
costomerTel.text = @"+86 18888888888"
[self addSubview:costomerTel];

UILabel *costomerDesc = [[UILabel alloc] init];
costomerDesc.textColor = RSColor(@"#0b192e");
costomerDesc.font = RSFont(12);
costomerDesc.text = @"北京·项目经理"
[self addSubview: costomerDesc];
```

Below is image, which is display in iPhone:
[the top label's color is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B54j0.png)

The RSColor code:

```
+ (UIColor *) colorWithHexString : (NSString *) color
{
   NSString *cString = [[color stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

// String should be 6 or 8 characters
if ([cString length] < 6) {
    return [UIColor clearColor];
}

// strip 0X if it appears
if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"])
    cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];
if ([cString hasPrefix:@"#"])
    cString = [cString substringFromIndex:1];
if ([cString length] != 6)
    return [UIColor clearColor];

// Separate into r, g, b substrings
NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = 2;

//r
NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

//g
range.location = 2;
NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

//b
range.location = 4;
NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

// Scan values
unsigned int r, g, b;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];



return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f) green:((float) g / 255.0f) blue:((float) b / 255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```

}

Any help is appreciate. Thank You

Comment: Where is this code located? ViewDidLoad?

Comment: I think its because RSColor. Try with UIColor once.

Comment: I upload the RSColor code , the code located is at ViewDidLoad

Comment: I use UIColor the color still not true color

Comment: Could you show difference between "true" and "false" colors for us?

Comment: The color I use NSLog print is my input string , but it display on my iPhone I saw there is not a same color .The system print two label textColor is  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0431373 0.0980392 0.180392 1'

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your this code with below code

```
// Separate into r, g, b substrings
NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = 2;
```

Replace with this Code

```
// If Hex String Has Alpha Component
    NSInteger startRange = 0;
    CGFloat colorAlpha = 1.0f;
    // Separate into a, r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.length = 2;
    if ([cString length] == 8) {
        range.location = startRange;
        NSString *aString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
        colorAlpha = [self alphaFromHexCode:aString];
        startRange = 2;
    }
```

Please let me know if you still facing issue.

```
+ (CGFloat)alphaFromHexCode:(NSString *)hexCode {
    unsigned int per;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:hexCode] scanHexInt:&per];
    return ((float) per / 255.0f);
}
```

Here it is and it will also convert your 8 digit hex color which may be we use in android and sometime web also.

so it is like @"00FFFFFF" means first two char contain the alpha of the color so you have to find out the alpha for that color.

Comment: What is the [self alphaFromHexCode:aString]; source code?